# Headless Chrome from Swift Process

Tags: swift, google-chrome

I'm having an issue trying to open headless chrome from a swift Process. I'm trying to use it to render a PDF. I think the launch path is the issue.. Thoughts?

```
let wk = Process()

wk.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
wk.arguments = []
wk.arguments?.append ("/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf http://www.google.com")

wk.launch()          
wk.waitUntilExit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start the process with the help of the bash
then you'll have to use the "-c" argument first, so that the
next argument is taken as commands to execute:

```
wk.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
wk.arguments = ["-c",
                "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf http://www.google.com"]
```

But note that you can start the application directly (avoiding
all problems with embedded space characters):

```
wk.launchPath = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
wk.arguments = ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--print-to-pdf", "http://www.google.com"]
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. However, now I'm getting errors thrown in Xcode. It seems to be a permissions issue. It says it successfully wrote the file, but it doesn't exist. I get: "Month 13 is out of bounds" a few times. And: failed to read /System/Library/Preferences/Logging/Subsystems/com.apple.launchservices.plist: [1: Operation not permitted]. Ideas?

Comment: @JoeBayLD:  Unfortunately not.